# im stuck trying to guess a password to a server im accessing through netcat for a ctf

Tags: passwords, netcat, cracking

im doing a ctf and given this server to netcat into but it requires a password and im given no info besides i have to guess the password? Any solutions guys?

i tried the netcat username then username and port number then password123 but none worked